# How to calculate p value and correlation coefficient for Spearman’s correlation of differential expression data with 40000 permutations?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I have 3 groups,let's call them g1, g2, g3. Each of them is a result of analysis in between groups of conditions, and g1 looks like this

```
                   geneSymbol      logFC         t      P.Value   adj.P.Val         Beta
EXykpF1BRREdXnv9Xk      MKI67 -0.3115880 -5.521186 5.772137e-07 0.008986062 4.3106665
0Tm7hdRJxd9zoevPlA     CCL3L3  0.1708020  4.162115 9.109798e-05 0.508784638 0.6630544
u_M5UdFdhg3lZ.qe64     UBE2G1 -0.1528149 -4.031466 1.430822e-04 0.508784638 0.3354065
lkkLCXcnzL9NXFXTl4     SEL1L3 -0.2138729 -3.977482 1.720517e-04 0.508784638 0.2015945
0Uu3XrB6Bd14qoNeuc      ZFP36  0.1667330  3.944917 1.921715e-04 0.508784638 0.1213335
3h7Sgq2i3sAUkxL_n8      ITGB5  0.3419488  3.938960 1.960886e-04 0.508784638 0.1066896
```

g2 and g2 look the same and each has  15568 entries (genes)

How to calculate p value and correlation coefficient for Spearman’s correlation for this data for 40000 permutations?

I joined all 3 groups, g1, g2, g3, and extracted only Beta (B)

I got this data frame, with matching 15568 entries:

```
                     Beta1       Beta2    Beta3
EXykpF1BRREdXnv9Xk -4.970533 -4.752771 -5.404054
0Tm7hdRJxd9zoevPlA -4.862168 -5.147294 -3.909654
u_M5UdFdhg3lZ.qe64 -5.368846 -5.396183 -5.405330
lkkLCXcnzL9NXFXTl4 -4.367704 -4.847795 -5.148524
0Uu3XrB6Bd14qoNeuc -5.286592 -4.949305 -5.278798
3h7Sgq2i3sAUkxL_n8 -4.579528 -2.403240 -4.710600
```

To calculate Spearman’s I could use in R:

```
> cor(d,use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="spearman")
        Beta1          Beta2        Beta3
Beta1 1.000000000  0.234171932  0.002474729
Beta2 0.234171932  1.000000000 -0.005469126
Beta3 0.002474729 -0.005469126  1.000000000
```

Can someone please tell me what would be the method to use to get correlation coefficient and p value taken in account number of permutations? And am I am correct to use Beta in order to do correlation in between these 3 groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint to access the `correlation coefficient` and `p-value` using the `psych` package. I'm going to use the `mtcars` dataset instead of re-typing your dataset as it is not in an easy `copy-paste (dput(df))` format.

```r
library(psych)
corr.test.col.1to4 <- corr.test(mtcars[1:4], method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")
names(corr.test.col.1to4)
#1] "r"      "n"      "t"      "p"      "se"     "sef"    "adjust" "sym"    "ci"     "ci.adj"
# [11] "Call"  

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# in your case you probably want to do

#cor.test.beta <- corr.test(d[c("Beta1","Beta2", "Beta3")], method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see from the output of `names(corr.test.col.1to4)`:

> r: correlation coefficient
>
> n: number of observation
>
> p: p.value
>
> se: standard error
>
> ci: confidence intervals

So, if you want the correlation coefficient you can pull the values out using

```r
corr.test.col.1to4$r
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.9108013 -0.9088824 -0.8946646
# cyl  -0.9108013  1.0000000  0.9276516  0.9017909
# disp -0.9088824  0.9276516  1.0000000  0.8510426
# hp   -0.8946646  0.9017909  0.8510426  1.0000000
```

The `p-values`

```r
corr.test.col.1to4$p
#               mpg          cyl         disp           hp
# mpg  0.000000e+00 2.345144e-12 2.548135e-12 1.017194e-11
# cyl  4.690287e-13 0.000000e+00 1.365266e-13 5.603057e-12
# disp 6.370336e-13 2.275443e-14 0.000000e+00 6.791338e-10
# hp   5.085969e-12 1.867686e-12 6.791338e-10 0.000000e+00
```

The standard errors

```r
corr.test.col.1to4$se
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp
# mpg  0.00000000 0.07537483 0.07614303 0.08156289
# cyl  0.07537483 0.00000000 0.06818175 0.07890355
# disp 0.07614303 0.06818175 0.00000000 0.09586909
# hp   0.08156289 0.07890355 0.09586909 0.00000000
```

The confidence intervals

```r
corr.test.col.1to4$ci
#               lower          r      upper            p
# mpg-cyl  -0.9559077 -0.9108013 -0.8237102 4.690287e-13
# mpg-disp -0.9549362 -0.9088824 -0.8200941 6.370336e-13
# mpg-hp   -0.9477078 -0.8946646 -0.7935207 5.085969e-12
# cyl-disp  0.8557708  0.9276516  0.9643958 2.275443e-14
# cyl-hp    0.8067919  0.9017909  0.9513377 1.867686e-12
# disp-hp   0.7143279  0.8510426  0.9251848 6.791338e-10
```

You can save the output on a variable and do further formatting to make the reporting just.

Your second question **Am I correct to use `Beta` in order to do correlation in between these 3 groups?** is a valid question which you need to answer/address depending on the question you want to answer as well as report it in such a way that the corr is computed on variable `Beta` and justify the choice of the variable `Beta` in your report.

Hope that helps.

Comment: HI @deepseefan thank you so much for this elaborate explanation, I would need to ask you also how do I put the number of permutations, say 40000 in this scenario?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think it is impractical if not much of a use to show the permutations. You might want to describe the number of participating elements (variables) which generates the total number of permutation, and use that to justify your design is balanced as potential bias that might occur say seeing `variable a` before `variable b` is addressed by using all possible combination/rotation/permutation of the variables in which they can possibly occur.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very helpful explanation and the code!

Comment: do you by any chance know how to change the corr.test(allF[1:3], method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs") in order to get better precision of resulted p values? Right now I am getting this: 0.0000000

Comment: try `corr.test(allF[1:3], method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")$p` or else look into `format.pval` or `options` to print as many significant digits as possible to get numbers other than zero.